# PL/SQL Invalid object identifier in creating procedure with date field parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im fairly new pl/sql and im trying to create procedure that can take a date parameter from input, find and update the matching join date row(s) from student table I am working on but i cant seem to get a valid date and i'm not sure i properly configured my procedure from input your help would be appreciated, this is my code currently.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dateChanger (p_join_date IN DATE) 
    IS p_date DATE;
       p_month VARCHAR2(3);
       p_year VARCHAR2(4); 
       p_change VARCHAR2(11); 
       v_month VARCHAR2(3);
    BEGIN
    p_date := to_date(p_join_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy');
    p_month := Extract(MONTH FROM p_date);
    p_year := Extract(YEAR FROM p_date);
    v_month := to_char(Extract(MONTH FROM student.join_date%TYPE), 'MON');
     --expected result 01-(Month from p_date)-(Year from p_date) eg. 01-JUL-2021
    p_change := '01-'+to_char(p_month, 'MON')+'-'+to_char(p_year, 'YYYY');-- date put back together
    UPDATE Week03.t_student SET join_date = to_date(p_change, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
    WHERE v_month = p_month; -- table updated where months match
    RETURN(p_date || '-----' || p_change);
END;    
/

ACCEPT jDate Date PROMPT 'Please Enter a valid date as dd-MON-YYYY eg. 13-JUL-2021';
DECLARE
dc VARCHAR2(11);
l_date student.join_date%type := &jDate; -- input from user saved to date type variable
 BEGIN
 dc := DATECHANGER(l_date);
 SELECT DATECHANGER(l_date) INTO dc from dual; 
 END;
  /
```

When i enter the date as 'dd-mon-yyy' or 'yyyy-mon-dd' and many other variations i get a pls 00905 & 00201 error any help would be appreciated. it seems the date input refuses all the variations i've tried.

Comment: `p_date := to_date(p_join_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy');` is rather odd. Isn't it already a date? And `to_date` takes a string, so first Oracle has to convert `p_date` into a string, but you don't say how, so it has to use the default NLS settings for the session. Then you assume the result if that will be in `'dd-mon-yyyy'` format. What if it isn't?

Comment: Also, `return somevalue` is only valid in a function, not a procedure, and I'm not sure what `extract(month from student.join_date%type)` is supposed to do. `%type` is only valid in the declaration section, where it means use the datatype of the referenced database object.

Comment: @William Robertson yea i noticed there was a lot errors in my code had to refactor it a lot when i learnt about trunc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea so for future references to anyone who may need to complete a similar task to mine here is how i solved my problem thanks a bit to @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dateChanger (p_join_date IN DATE) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Week03.t_student SET join_date = trunc(join_date, 'MM');
END;
/
SELECT * FROM student;
BEGIN
 dateChanger(to_date('2018-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> DATE
>
> Makes reply a valid DATE format. If the reply is not a valid DATE
> format, ACCEPT gives an error message and prompts again. The datatype
> is CHAR.

That means in this case result of accept of data is char format.

You should change you code a bit.
in announmous block

```
l_date student.join_date%type := &jDate; => l_date varchar2(100) := '&jDate'
```

and in procedure

```
 (p_join_date IN DATE)  => (p_join_date in varchar2)
```